# Conversations tab in Mathematics chatroom is not displaying

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I have noticed this yesterday for the first time, I don't know whether this problem exists for longer time. When I go to the [information page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) about the chatroom called Mathematics and click on the [conversations tab](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics?tab=conversations), I am directed to [this error page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/info/36/mathematics) instead of begin shown all bookmarked conversations.

The other tabs on that site are working fine for me.

Comment: Hmm, I can reproduce this on the Mathematics room and the Bridge, but not other rooms including TL which has a lot of bookmarked conversations.

Comment: I've asked the same thing at [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181463/conversations-tab-in-some-chatroom-is-not-displaying), we will see whether it helps to get at least some answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181467/115866):

Fixed now. There was an edge case in getting the "conversation ended" time where we ended up with an unexpected null value.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed! Thank you.